# list value shorted in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I put some urls inside of the list but it shows only "..., " for every items more than 5. the message is this:

```
I/flutter ( 8408): [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bagom-4caee.appspot.com/o/princess.jpg?alt=media&token=355b8b56-1d40-4878-993b-6a80719caf7e, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bagom-4caee.appspot.com/o/hensel.jpg?alt=media&token=1f4db537-853d-4c51-96a5-c76c05cd55ae, ..., https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bagom-4caee.appspot.com/o/jungle.jpg?alt=media&token=a3bd7483-df7e-4cd1-81aa-1992d3596519, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bagom-4caee.appspot.com/o/teleport.jpg?alt=media&token=de7fc28b-1652-4d78-ad50-da5d80fef3fb, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bagom-4caee.appspot.com/o/island.jpg?alt=media&token=0f0532ec-801b-4ff0-99a5-b0f6b523c259]
```

I have 7 items in the list, but it only shows 5 and the other 2 are "...,". the other one just shows "...," instead of the actual URL. I think this is why GridView inside the FutureBuilder is causing the problem because of the index.

How can I fix the problem? Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: toList() instead of toString() worked